# Dictionary Not Writable (generic old setup.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I am trying to set up a Python extension (Gambit, http://gambit.sourceforge.net/gambit13/build.html) and am getting an error when trying to build setup.py:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 32, in <module>
>
> m.Extension.**dict** = m._Extension.**dict**
>
> AttributeError: attribute '**dict**' of 'type' objects is not writable

This seems to be an issue with a certain type of (older) setup.py file. I created a minimal example based on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools_cython/0.2:

```
#Using Python 3.6 on Windows 10 (64-bit)

from setuptools import setup
#from distutils.extension import Extension
#^That line can be included or excluded without changing the error    

import sys
if 'setuptools.extension' in sys.modules:
    m = sys.modules['setuptools.extension']
    m.Extension.__dict__ = m._Extension.__dict__
```

Other packages have had similar problems in the past (see arcitc issue #17 on Github) and apparently fixed it by some Python magic which goes above my head (arctic's setup.py no longer includes the relevant lines).

Any thoughts on what could cause the issue? If so, are there any changes I can make to setup.py to avoid this error without breaking the underlying functionality?

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Python, it used to be that the `__dict__` object of classes could be changed to point to a different dictionary. That changed with the advent of new-style classes (those descended from `object`). You had to explicitly specify `object` in Python 2.x classes to get that behavior; in Python 3, this is the standard (and only) behavior, as Python 3 does not support old-style classes at all.

My guess is that the module you're trying to use was written for Python 2, does not explicitly inherit from `object`, and expects an old-style class, but is getting a new-style class because Python 3. In other words, it's not compatible with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is somewhat untested I'm afraid.

I think @kindall has probably correctly diagnosed the issue. I think the solution is to remove the offending 4 lines from https://github.com/gambitproject/gambit/blob/master/src/python/setup.py.

You then want to change it so

```
#at the top
from Cython.Build import cythonize

#at the bottom

setup(
    # some lines skipped
    ext_modules=cythonize([libgame]),
    # etc
    )
```

See http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html for how Cython expects modules to be built now.

(I'd expect to run into other Python 3 issues though)